# Example how to read from XML file several values and compare them efficiently with a value

Tags: c, xml

This is really a two scale question. How can we read efficiently several values from an XML file and then how can we compare them with a different value.

It is very important to be done as efficiently as possible which is really what the question is about.

Here is an example of the existing code:

```
if (strcasecmp(stMsgData->paramName,"Device.a.b") == 0)
    {
        ret = aFunction();
    }
    else if (strcasecmp(stMsgData->paramName,"Device.z.o") == 0)
    {
        ret = bFunction();
    }
    else if (strcasecmp(stMsgData->paramName,"Device.g.j") == 0)
    {
        ret = cFunction();
    }
```

For the shake of a better example, lets assume that Device.a.b is really Device.DeviceInfo.ManufacturerOUI. The main thing we want to achieve is that "Device.DeviceInfo.ManufacturerOUI" could also be "Device.DeviceInfo.OUI" or "Device.DeviceInfo.ManfOUI" and so on. As we want to avoid recompiling and go and update code for possibly 600 items or more, the best approach seems to be to do this comparison from an XML (alternatives to XML are welcome if more sensible) file. The question is, how could this be achieved (example code) in the most efficient way and if there are any further suggestions.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In short: performance concerns here are spurious, reading from file is magnitudes slower than comparisons and several branches.

### Practice concern: Premature optimisation

Really this whole thing stinks of *premature optimisation*. **Especially** since you're reading this data **from a file**. Therefore, if you are just reading values from the file, the performance is going to be mainly down to how fast you are reading the file, because:

- File access (in general) is magnitudes slower than your comparisons, unless it is cached by the OS.
- Reading XML correctly is a lot slower than these types of comparisons. Reading an XML file quickly is still very slow, relatively.

Do not worry so much about performance and focus on a good design, without necessarily trying every *cool thing* you can think of like XML. You can always profile it later and optimise it.

**If you really want this to be fast, I think the main difference you could make would be *not using XML*.** It appears this was a choice in your project, which brings me onto the next part of my answer.

### Design concern: Building your project

I think you need to research building a bit more. You were concerned about having to rebuild your 'entire project' every time you change some values, but there are legitimate ways around this, such as storing these values in separate compilation units. Then you can just recompile that one file when you change the values and re-link the project. The method that they're exposed to the rest of the project with is up to you, but global constant variables is probably the best way to go for C.

### Comparing strings

Presume we don't store the values in a separate compilation unit.

Given that you say you want to be able to check for hundreds of possible strings, I think you should aid this check with a string [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Provide keys for each possible value, if some of the allowed keys have alternatives then the mapped values in the table could contain unique identifiers for each type of key.

e.g. "Device.DeviceInfo.ManufacturerOUI" and "Device.DeviceInfo.OUI" could both map to the ID `DEVICE_INFO_OUI`.